Unable to connect PgAdmin to RDS instance
Everything was working fine until one day I was not able to connect my local pgadmin to rds and am getting this error since -
connection failed: FATAL: pg_hba.conf rejects connection for host "my ip", user "postgres", database "rdsadmin", SSL encryption
connection to server at "rds db link" (), port 5432 failed: FATAL: pg_hba.conf rejects connection for host "my ip", user "postgres", database "rdsadmin", no encryption
I've tried changing force_ssl values in my parameter group to 0 and 1, still not working. I am able to access the db via my python code though. Would really appreciate some help on this!
